# What is "B4c0/\/" in bcrypt implementation for nodejs

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

This may be totally naieve, but I would like to know what is the meaning of `"B4c0/\/"` in the code example below. Thanks.

From github:

```
To hash a password:

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash("B4c0/\/", salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
    });
});
To check a password:

// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compare("B4c0/\/", hash, function(err, res) {
    // res == true
});
bcrypt.compare("not_bacon", hash, function(err, res) {
    // res = false
});
```

Comment: Just an example password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a password being hashed. Just an example.

Comment: Nice, when you are new to this stuff the documentation doesn't help. In this case, you did though.